# How do I prevent the camera to open after changing the orientation of the screen

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating an app for scanning text from image files. I used an action bar and used camera icon.

When i click on the camera icon, camera will start and scan part will be extracted from images, then it will goes to number of textviews to store scan data. This is working fine.

I want to save the data even when the screen orientation is changed. But, when i change the orientation, the camera starts automatically. How can I prevent the camera to open up?

Thank you.

I tried on google but i did not get the relevant answers for this.

Comment: Adding some code might help to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid camera open again on orientation change, pls add 
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to your activity in AndroidMenifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.xyz.myactivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```